# Highcharts line chart not loading data

Tags: jquery, highcharts, tooltip, line

I have been using `highcharts` and trying to use the custom tooltip.

here is my working [sample code](http://jsfiddle.net/sonikunal/oobk15bd/2/).

The tooltip can be seen by moving mouse on the graph.

However this same graph does not work when it has lots of data e.g. [data of around 2 days](http://jsfiddle.net/sonikunal/oobk15bd/3/).

If we change the `json` data to be like this.

> [1494700238000, 180], [1494700537000, 180]....

Than it will load the graph properly.

But then we cannot use the tooltip, which is required by my client.

Comment: Set series.turboThreshold to 0 http://jsfiddle.net/oobk15bd/5/ http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.area.turboThreshold

Answer (score 0):

If I properly understand your problem, you have encountered [highcharts error number 12](https://www.highcharts.com/errors/12). Highcharts library processes series data using a threshold, which is equal 1000 by default. This threshold is triggerred only if you set data as array of configuration objects. That's why your chart is loaded with list of numbers, but not with list of objects. The reason it's clear - it takes lots of time to process such a huge amounts of objects with parameters that could vary a lot. Here I can see three possible ways:

a) The most obvious one - disable this threshold policy, you can see it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/arcquim/oobk15bd/4/):

```
plotOptions: {
  series: {
     pointStart: Date.UTC(2017, 4, 15),
     turboThreshold: 0
  }
}
```

This solution is based on [highcharts api](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.series.turboThreshold), and is very simple. But this can lead to loading unlimited amount of data to the client, that can lead to browser memory leak.

b) The second solution is to load some appropriate data amount to the client by default (let's say 1000 points), and give a user opportunity to [zoom](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/chart/zoomtype-x/) data, loading more detailed information only after zooming. It's the most complex, but the most flexible way.

c) The third approach is to set some threshold based on your data (for example, 10000). This defends you from client slowness, is not very difficult, but not very flexible - you have to change this constant every time amount of your points has increased.